# Elasticsearch query with exclusion list

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a typical newsletter system that has an index (contact) in which we store contact information. These are typical personal data: name, email address, etc., and answers to questions that are important to us.
Most data types are simple keyword (or date) because these are the best for our searches. The number of documents is ~ 1 million.

The query e.g. "I am looking for all women aged 25-50 who live in Budapest". (our queries are much more complex than this)

```
GET /contact/_search
{
  "query": {
      "bool": {
        "should": [
          {
              "term": {
                  "city": "Budapest"
              }
          },
          {
              "term": {
                  "gender": "female"
              }
          },
          {
              "range": {
                  "birthdate": {
                      "lte": "1995-05-14",
                      "gte": "1970-05-14"
                  }
              }
          }
        ]
      }
  }
}
```

This works very well for us, extremely fast.

My question would be, how do I make a large exclusion list for regular queries?

Each contact has an ID (md5 hash or sha256) and we want to query e.g. "I am looking for all women aged 20-50 who live in Budapest and do not have their ID on the exclusion list."

The exclusion list is currently e.g. a csv file with an hash column and e.g. 250,000 or 3,000,000 records.

I don’t know how this list should be put in the database, nor how it should be referenced in the query.

Could someone help me?

Comment: One way could be to not index data (contact list ) for ids in the exclusion list. This way index size is reduced and no need to handle this search time

Comment: If the exclusion list are same for all your queries, you could translate it to a boolean field on each document, then add a filter clause to you query.

Comment: Unfortunately, the exclusion list is never the same.

This exclusion list is similar to NOT IN, NOT EXISTS in SQL.
In one table the contacts, in another table the exclusion list:

SELECT c. * FROM contact c WHERE c.age BETWEEN 20-50 AND c.city = 'Budapest' and NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM exlusion e WHERE c.md5hash = e.md5hash)

I want to achieve this in elasticsearch. Is this conceivable with two indices? One index contact, another index exclusion?

Answer (score 0):

Or we give a name to the exclusion list (ID). The contact object gets a property called exclude which will be a list and contains the ID of the exclusion list that contains the contact document. This would make it easy to query. It would be similar to tags.

E.g: exclusion list in csv file, 200,000 records. List name is ex_20200515_xyz

```
{
"email": "xyz@gmail.com",
"birthday": "1975-01-01",
"city": "Budapest",
....
excludes: ["ex_20200510_rtz", "ex_20200515_xyz"]
}
```